# Slim not displaying properly in Rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have a sample slim document I am trying to run in my homepage rails app.

My `application.html.slim` file is as follows:

```
doctype html
html
  head
  title Tasks
  = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  = csrf_meta_tags

  javascript:
    alert('Welcome!')

  body
  = yield
```

I've added:

```
gem 'slim-rails'
```

to my Gemfile, and ran `bundle install`, and nothing. I've also added:

```
Slim::Engine.default_options[:pretty] = true
```

to my confif/environments/development.rb file...and nothing. I just get the output of my application.html.slim file.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

`gem 'slim'` to my Gemfile, deleted `Gemfile.lock`, and ran `bundle install` again, and it worked. Not sure if `'slim-rails'` is defunct, or if it requires the `slim` gem in order to work.